# Varnish: cache only specific domain

Tags: performance, apache, dns, varnish

I have been Googling aggressively, but without luck.

I'm using Varnish with great results, but I would like to host multiple websites on a single server (Apache), without Varnish caching all of them.

Can I specify what websites by URL to cache?

Thanks

Answer (score 32):

*(edited after comment)* It's req.http.host, so in your vcl file (e.g. default.vcl) do:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  # dont cache foo.com or bar.com - optional www
   if (req.http.host ~ "(www\.)?(foo|bar)\.com") {
     pass;
   }
  # cache foobar.com - optional www
   if (req.http.host ~ "(www\.)?foobar\.com") {
     lookup;
   }
}
```

And in varnish3-vcl:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  # dont cache foo.com or bar.com - optional www
   if (req.http.host ~ "(www\.)?(foo|bar)\.com") {
     return(pass);
   }
  # cache foobar.com - optional www
   if (req.http.host ~ "(www\.)?foobar\.com") {
     return(lookup);
   }
}
```

Comment: Great, pointed me in the right direction I think. But isn't it req.http.host? http://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCL

Comment: You're right, thanks! It's req.http.host (and req.url). I fixed it in the example.

Comment: Do you *have* to *pass* the foo and bar domains explicitly, or would it be enough to only *lookup* the desired domain? In other words, is it enough to define a whitelist?

Comment: If you only define a white or a black-list (i.e.; you don't exit your own vcl_recv function with an action like pass, lookup, etc), then the default behavior of vcl_recv is applied. Please read about it at http://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleDefault and study default.vcl. To answer your question: yes you have to pass them. If you don't pass the foo and bar domains explicitly, and your GET or HEAD request contains no auth or cookie header, it will be looked up.

Comment: That works for Varnish 2. You should update your answer to include the Varnish 3 code too, which is return (pass) and return(pipe).

Comment: If this doesn't work, make sure that `sub vcl_fetch {` has a corresponding `return(hit_for_pass);` wherever there's a `return(pass);` in `sub vcl_recv {`

Comment: I would strongly recommend not hardcoding "return(lookup)". Clean up the request and then let the default policy decide if it can cache it or not. When forcing caching you're halfway to caching session cookies which can be disastrous.

Answer (score 6):

Yes,

in vcl_recv you just match the hosts that you would like *not* to cache and pass them. Something like this (untested):

```
vcl_recv {
   # dont cache foo.com or bar.com - optional www
   if (req.host ~ "(www)?(foo|bar).com") {
     return(pass);
   }
}
```

Comment: @CamiloFlores you should rollback and post your edit as new answer (or comment to this post)

Comment: do not ever use pipe, it is a nightmare when you have multiple backends and or keepalive connections that have any header handled by varnish

Comment: I have no idea why I did a return(pipe) here. Sorry about creating confusion.

Comment: I tried that and the varnish does not start. Why to publish untested info?

Comment: you miss the `sub vcl_recv` and the `req.http.host`

Answer (score 2):

### For Varnish 4

replace lookup with **hash**

default.vcl:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  # dont cache foo.com or bar.com - optional www
   if (req.http.host ~ "(www\.)?(foo|bar)\.com") {
     return(pass);
   }
  # cache foobar.com - optional www
   if (req.http.host ~ "(www\.)?foobar\.com") {
     return(hash);
   }
}
```